# Formatting a SQL query

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I have as an input a string that is a SQL query. I need to get all tables that the query uses (like FROM **table** or **table1** INNER JOIN **table2**). But the query does not respect any standard. So my question is if there is any method to format the query so that searching for these table names is easier.

My method right now is to search for the keywords from and join and take whatever line is after the keyword (or before in the case of the join), but there are exceptions in the queries where the from does not have a newline after it and I have to treat every exception like this. I don't think regex works because while the table name is {schema_name.table_name} there are also columns like that.

```py
for row in text:
    to_append = None
    split_row = row.strip('\r').strip(' ').strip('\r').split(' ')
    if split_row[-1].lower() == "from" and len(split_row) > 1:
        from_indexes.append(text.index(row))
    if ("join" in split_row or "JOIN" in split_row) and (split_row[-1] != "join" and split_row[-1]
                                                         != "JOIN"):
        for ind in range(len(split_row)):
            if split_row[ind].lower() == "join":
                to_append = split_row[ind + 1:]
                row = split_row[:ind + 1]
                row = ' '.join(row)
    rows.append(row.strip('\r').strip(' ').strip('\t'))
    if to_append is not None:
        rows.append(' '.join(to_append))
```

So I am looking for some method that can standardize the sql query or for another method to extract the table names from the query.

Comment: why do you want to do this? it's very awkward in the general case, e.g. what should you get back from `WITH x AS (SELECT 'SELECT 1 FROM foo' AS y) SELECT * FROM x;`?

Comment: If both foo and x are not temporary tables then I want both foo and x.

Comment: it was a rhetorical question!  `x` is a CTE, hence not a "real" table, but might be interesting depending on what you're trying to do. `foo` is a bit of text embedded in a string, hence should almost certainly be ignored by any reasonable tool.  if you're writing code to parse SQL these are the standard sorts of issues you need to think about and deal with

Comment: I'm building an app that finds dependencies of tables in other databases. One of the tables has meta data including a column with sql queries and the non-temporary tables after the from/join keyword are treated as dependencies so that is why I need to parse SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a more straightforward approach would be to use *regular expressions*:

```
import re

sql = """select t1.*, t2.y, sq.z, table3.q from table1 t1 join
    table2 t2 on t1.x = t2.x left join
    (select 5 as x, 9 as z) sq JOIN
    table3 on sq.x = table3.x
;"""

matches = re.findall(r'(\s+(from|join)\s+)(\w+)', sql, re.DOTALL|re.IGNORECASE)
for match in matches:
    print(match[2])
```

Note that it will not consider **(select 5 as x, 9 as z)** as a table.

Comment: This seems to be the answer. Works much better than my algorithm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an ORM tool in order to make cleaner queries (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). Or at least some query builder modules.

I recently found a remake of laravels "eloquent" orm here https://pypi.org/project/eloquent/.

Other ORMs like PeeWee are pretty common to use, too.

Comment: I don't make the queries. I don't have any way of changing them.